# While Python is writing to CSV, the script is inserting new line in try / except block in the csv file

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, index-error

Good day,

I am pretty new to Python and Selenium, and need help with the following issue:

A snippet of my code is as follows:

```
num_page_items = len(date)
blank = "0"
try:
    with open('results.csv', 'a') as f:
        for i in range(num_page_items):
            f.write(name[i].text + "#" + surname[i].text + "#" + ref[i].text + "#" + url[i].text + "\n")
except IndexError:
    with open('results.csv', 'a') as f:
            f.write(blank)
```

I have a few variables that are scraping a website using selenium.
An example of the data and expected output as follows:

> Name: Joe Surname: Soap Ref: 1234 URL: www.example.com
>
> Name: Bill Surname: Smith Ref: 4567 URL: www.dot.com

[expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnvL8.png)

when all elements are present the Python script works well, however when one element (in the example: Ref doesn't exist in the second entry) doesn't exist the output is as follows

[output when an element doesn't exist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGrwS.png)

what can I do to set the variable to "Null" if the variable doesn't exist on the webpage so the expected new output would be as follows:

[expected output when element doesn't exist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMz5A.png)

> Just as a side note, the error I receive isn't a Selenium exception,
>   but is an IndexError, hence the use of the "IndexError" except
>   statement

***EDIT - Felipe Gutierrez's Suggestion***

larger piece of the code with Felipe's suggestion:

```
for url in links:
        driver.get(url) #goes to the array and opens each link

        company = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("""//*[contains(@id, 'node')]/div[2]/ul/li/div/div[1]/span""") 
        date = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("""//*[contains(@id, 'node')]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/span""")
        ref = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("""//*[contains(@id, 'node')]/div[1]/div[3]""")
        title = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("""//*[@id="page-title"]/span""")
        urlinf = driver.current_url

        num_page_items = len(date)
        blank = "blank"

        for ref in ref:
            if ref is None:
                ref = 0

        with open('results.csv', 'a') as f:
            for i in range(num_page_items):
                f.write(company[i].text + "#" + date[i].text + "#" + ref[i].text + "#" + title[i].text + "#" + urlinf + "\n")

driver.close()
```

I now get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "accc_for_loop_nest.py",
>   line 50, in 
>       f.write(company[i].text + "#" + date[i].text + "#" + ref[i].text + "#" + title[i].text + "#" + urlinf + "\n") TypeError: 'WebElement'
>   object does not support indexing

Comment: You should really consider using csv module (that's what it's for),

Comment: Thanks. Could you provide an example that would fit what I am looking to achieve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You loose the index of the lists you are iterating on with the try-catch, you can try testing for the IndexError values before the insertion loop and assign a zero to the list at that specific place. Than do the insertion without the exception handling.
Something like:

```
for url in links:
    driver.get(url) #goes to the array and opens each link

    company = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("""//*[contains(@id, 'node')]/div[2]/ul/li/div/div[1]/span""") 
    date = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("""//*[contains(@id, 'node')]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/span""")
    ref = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("""//*[contains(@id, 'node')]/div[1]/div[3]""")
    title = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("""//*[@id="page-title"]/span""")
    urlinf = driver.current_url

    num_page_items = len(date)
    blank = "blank"

    companyStrings = []
    dateStrings = []
    refStrings = []
    titleStrings = []

    with open('results.csv', 'a') as f:
            for i in range(num_page_items):
                companyStrings.append( company[i].text )
                dateStrings.append( date[i].text )
                refStrings.append( ref[i].text )
                titleStrings.append( title[i].text ) 
                if companyStrings[i] == '':
                    companyStrings[i] = '0'
                if dateStrings[i] = '':
                    dateStrings[i] = '0'
                if refStrings[i] == '':
                    refStrings[i] = '0'
                if titleStrings[i] == '':
                    titleStrings[i] = '0'
                f.write(companyStrings[i] + "#" + dateStrings[i] + "#" + refStrings[i] + "#" + titleStrings[i] + "#" + urlinf + "\n")

driver.close()
```

Comment: thanks Felipe, I have made an edit to my post to add what you have suggested, but I get another error now - not sure if I am placing the new for loop in the correct place.

Comment: I updated my answer test it and let me know as I dont have how to test it right now.

Comment: Update I got a computer and tested it, it should work now.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I tried your update and now get the following error:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "accc_for_loop_nest.py", line 58, in <module>
    if len(company[i]) == 0:
TypeError: object of type 'WebElement' has no len()`

Comment: just tried again - still the same error.
I have tried None, "", ''
all output the same error

Comment: I need to know what the string lists contain when there is no element as I have no way to test, so skip the if's statements and see what values you get when there is no string, then use that knowledge to fill the if's, I added if titleStrings[i] == '': as that is what I guess there would be when there is no element but is probably other string.

Comment: Comment all the if's and let me know what you get when there is no value.

Comment: thanks, that's a good idea. I hashed out the if statements and had a look at whats being outputted. it looks like the element that "doesn't exist" is coming up as another element due to the xpath that I am using.
eg: xpath1 = 1, xpath2 = 2, xpath3 = 3, however if xpath 2 doesn't exist then its copying just a portion of xpath 3.
I will have to relook at how I select items - let me change them and come back to you.
while I am at it, any "best" driver.find.elements.x for this scenario ?
they all have predefined starting text, ie: Name: Surname: etc

Comment: Maybe this can help you? https://github.com/felipunky/GISPython/blob/master/Selenium.py here I selected the elements by x.find_elements_by_tag_name() and then I culled them by elements.find_elements_by_link_text()